# Update Table column with values for other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table along these lines:

```
Client | Date       | Value 1 | Value 2 |
1       2013-11-08    159      159
1       2013-11-09    254      254
1       2013-12-05    512      512
1       2014-01-02    1200     1200
2       2013-11-10    189      189
2       2013-11-15    289      289
2       2013-12-22    585      585
2       2014-01-06    1650     1650
```

I need to update the table in SQL to look like this:

```
Client | Date       | Value 1 | Value 2 |
1       2013-11-08    159      1200
1       2013-11-09    254      1200
1       2013-12-05    512      1200
1       2014-01-02    1200     1200
2       2013-11-10    189      1650
2       2013-11-15    289      1650
2       2013-12-22    585      1650
2       2014-01-06    1650     1650
```

The idea is that for each Client, `Value 2` will become `Value 1` where `Date` is most recent.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: microsoft SQL Database

Comment: that is a crazy design, why duplicate data?

Comment: It's a very complicated thing that my client wants. I don't understand it too. :)

Comment: @KM. - Especially since he's going to need to update every row when he next updates the table.  If there's a performance problem I could understand creating a separate "most recent value" table, but not creating a separate column...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server the best best thing to use is CTE with `UPDATE` statement. The query below demonstrates the syntax for what you need to do. All you have to do is substitute your table name and columns names.

```
;WITH    MyUpdate
          AS ( SELECT ClientId
                   ,Value1
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY MyDate DESC ) AS RowNum
                FROM MyTable)
    UPDATE MyTable
        SET MyTable.Value2 = MyUpdate.Value1
        FROM MyTable
        INNER JOIN MyUpdate
            ON MyUpdate.ClientID = MyTable.ClientID
               AND RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T2 SET Value2 =
(SELECT T1.Value2 FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE T1.Client = T2.Client AND
T1.Date = (SELECT MAX(T3.Date) FROM TABLE1 T3 
           WHERE T2.Client = T3.Client GROUP BY Client));
```

### [ORACLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72de9/1)